# How do I filter out only items from a list which is in an even position?

Tags: python

Instead of processing items based on its value, I need to run a function based on the item's position. This is an example of filtering based on the content of the list.

```
only_words = filter(str.isalpha, my_list)
```

I want to create a slice of the list that contains only items in the even position, that is:

```
new_list = []
pos = 0
for item in my_list:
   if pos % 2 == 0:
       new_list.append(item)
```

This is way too ugly. Better suggestions ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use this: `my_list[::2]` (for odd — `my_list[1::2]`)

Comment: That gives the odd positions. You mean `my_list[::2]`.

Comment: Could you possible explain this? Is '::' a special operator? Never saw something like this.

Comment: @lazyr Thanks, I always mix up these words. :-(

Comment: Generally slicing looks like `lst[start:stop:stride]`.  If you omit any of them, it starts from the beginning, stops at the end, and uses a stride of one; `lst[::2]` starts with the first element then counts by 2s.

Comment: @naeg And if you want formal definition (from [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html)): '...“extended slicing” with a third “step” parameter: `a[i:j:k]` selects all items of `a` with index `x` where `x = i + n*k`, `n >= 0` and `i <= x < j`'.

Answer (score 6):

```
[v for k, v in enumerate(mylist) if k % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: Slicing is better, but `enumerate()` needs more love.